# tracking focus gain and loss of a form in a VCL application

Tags: c++, windows, trace, c++builder-6

I maintain a windows desktop application that constantly removes the focus from its visible windows (and also from other applications on the desktop). This is clearly an error and I want to fix it, but the application is old (Borland C++Builder 6) and its code it very extensive. I try to trace `FormActivate` and `FormDeactivate` events but each of them only happens once: `FormActivate` after showing and `FormDeactivate` when closing the window.

Is it possible to programmatically track the focus changes to VCL forms?

Comment: Sometimes a really obnoxious bug in a very old program is just the thing needed to motivate the powers that be to throw it out or have it completely refactored - but you probably can't use that.  Have you looked at "detours" or tools like it which allow you to intercept the windows calls by injecting code to re-route?

Comment: Thanks. (1) There would be nothing that I would like more than to throw away that old code, but it's hopeless now (I'm struggling with the next release), but soon I will. (2) Detours I didn't know, it seems to do the job, but I fear that there is not enough money and time (to get it cooperating with the VCL framework?). I hoped there would be a much simpler trick. So I'm going to try to "hook" `WindowProc` now...

Answer (score 0):

The `TForm::OnActivate` event is triggered when the Form is initially shown, and when focus has moved to another Form within the same application process and then back.

The `TForm::OnDeactivate` event is triggered when the Form is being hidden, and when focus is moving to another Form within the same application process.

When focus is moving to another process, and then back to your process, the `TForm::OnActivate` and `TForm::OnDeactivate` events are NOT triggered.  The `TApplication::OnActivate` and `TApplication::OnDeactivate` events are triggered instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. *`TApplication::OnActivate and TApplication::OnDeactivate events are triggered`* - yes, in some cases. But if the focus changes within the same application, that causes WM_ACTIVATE being passed to `WindowProc`, which I found out by hooking the event of the same name.